# Master detail navigation crashes iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a menu for my app, which consists of different buttons to open something. The problem I'm facing is whenever I click a specific button, the whole thing crashes. It works perfectly fine on Android tho, this is iOS exclusive.

This is my Clicked event handler:

```
    public void HistoryPage(object sender, EventArgs e){
        History.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("cc206b");
        History.TextColor = Color.FromHex("ffffff");
        try{
            MasterLogin.History master = new MasterLogin.History();
            master.mainPage = mainPage;
            mainPage.Master = master;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Debug.WriteLine("Error en history: {0}",ex);   
        }
    }
```

I have pretty much the same code for every button and it works, but not for this one. Same thing goes for the views they show.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue was solved by restarting Visual Studio, cleaning and rebuilding the solution. Now it's working just fine, smh.